# Margin settings ignored by subsection titles and list items

Tags: lists, margins

My apologies for asking such a simple question. As a first time user, I am not using LaTeX to its fullest extent, although I do need its basic formatting option to work.

While 99% of my document ([downloadable here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_9VCQFtXUJAVXFjbWg0MW9wcjQ/view?usp=sharing), [template additionally found here](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/stylish-article)) renders correctly, the margins of its pages and its columns are not respected by a single subsection title and list item (a static bibliography entry).

[image: Margin Error]

I have tried using \allowbreak to fiddle around with the subsection title, but was unsuccesful. Any other suggestions are much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem for the subsection title. As for the bibliography, you can allow a break point writing `Val\-puesta`.

Comment: Odd, I am using TexMaker, all settings on default, and clicking Quick Build. What type of rendering would you recommend?

Comment: This has nothing to see with the editor. At any chance try the normal compiler (`F6`). Also, try adding `\raggedright` in `\titleformat{subsection]{…}`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately the normal compiler renders my document in the same way. Adding `\titleformat{subsection}{\raggedright}` to the top of my document, or just adding `{\raggedright}` in the titleformat subsection part of the .cls gives me errors.

Comment: Breaking up Valpuesta manually works great, by the way!

Comment: It's not exactly breaking it up, but allowing to break it if necessary. I wrote in the .class file:   `\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\color{color1}\sffamily\bfseries\raggedright}
  {\thesubsection}
  {0.5em}
  {#1}
  []`  and had no problem. Very strange… You also can try, as a workaround, to write:  
\subsection{ Enrichment occurs evenly at branch points \\ along immunostained axons}  provided you add the titlesec option `newlinetotoc`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25504/discussion-between-chris-and-bernard).